# Python post build to change an msi name wiht Branding and Version?

Tags: python, string

Hi I run a Build system for the company i work for...

Currently I am using a dictionary function to take the name of the msi that is produced by the builds and renaming to the naming convention decided up for that release.

```
def Rename_MSI(dict):
    global Src_Dir
    for msi in dict.keys():
        if os.path.exists(Src_Dir + "\\" + msi):
            print "renaming ", msi, "to ", dict[msi]
            os.rename(Src_Dir + "\\" + msi, Src_Dir + "\\" + dict[msi])
        else:
            print "Rename function failed", msi, "does not exist"
            sys.exit(3)
```

the name being produced by the teams is becoming standardized as well so I am sure I can do a rename without maintaining a dictionary moving forward.
The MSI Name is this as it comes from the build:
ProductSolution_x64.msi

I need to add the branding to the beginning Like this
Brand_ProductSolution_x64.msi

And the versioning like this:
Brand_ProductSolution_10_2_?_x64.msi

I thought about this kind of function but I am not really good with slicing:
str[:len(str)-8]

so something like this?
   newname=  % + str + % str[:len(str)-8] % (brand, version)

Thanks in advance for any assistance

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

msi = "ProductSolution_x64.msi"

name,arch = os.path.splitext(msi)[0].split('_')    

newname = "%s_%s_%s_%s.msi" %(brand, name, version, arch)
```

Should work...

Comment: hey one more question ed.
I am not familiar with the split you are using I see you are using '_' as the split identifier but what is the [0]?

I think i can use this same method butneed to modify that part of the function to work with this other set of msi which have
Brand_ProductSolution_x64.msi

Comment: The [0] means the split is applied to the first part of the splitext call ( in other words the filename without the extension). In this case split will return three elements, so just say: brand,name,arch = ... with the rest being identical to before.

Comment: OK I think i understand it :) thanks so much for the help.
If I want all the names to be completely lowercase would this work:
newname = string.lower("%s_%s_%s_%s.msi" %(brand, name, version, arch))  I really wish I was more adept at remembering what I can do with strings lol